# Copy 4 worksheets from workbook A which contains 5 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy 4 worksheets from workbook A which contains 5 worksheets and create a new workbook B and paste the copied worksheets in the new workbook.

I have done it for one sheet. how can i ameliorate this code :

```
Sub test()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy

    'Saving the new workbook B
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\John\B.xls", FileFormat:=18
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution is create the new workbook (B) and then navigate through the worksheets of workbook (A) copying only the worksheets you want.

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.name = "<name of worksheet you don't wanto to copy>" Then
            ws.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```